# Jupyter Print statement issue

Tags: python, jupyter

I am writing my first program in Jupiter(do note I have nil programming experience), I have written below program to simply print pay however I am running into the below error message? can somebody guide me what I am doing wrong

```
# Worked Exercise: 2.3

#my first program to get name and calc pay rate

name = input("Enter your name")
print = ("Hello ",name)

hour = input("Enter number of hours: ")
p_rate = input("Enter Pay rate: ")

pay = float(hour) * float(p_rate)

print("Calculated Salary is ",pay)
#pay <- this works, however, fails if I use print statement
```

I get the below error message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-50753a76d716> in <module>
     12 #pay
     13 
---> 14 print("Calculated Salary is ",pay)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print = ("Hello ",name)

is the mistake in your code. 
Removing that will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a ton for spoting This, i wouldnt have figured this out in an eternity !

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you have accidentally made a tuple called `print` and that tuple is called instead of the `print()` function.

That most likely happened by typing `print = ("Calculated Salary is ",pay)` or something similar.

Use `del print` to delete the tuple you made.
`del` removes things from memory.

When using python with a console, like in Jupyter, you must pay attention to what you have declared before new instructions.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your feedback, this are valuable for my journey up ahead in learning Python !